# Page won't scroll; using CSS fixed position tables

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, fixed

It's been years since I have done any heavy duty HTML/CSS work, and I recently started an overhaul of my company's website. I'm pretty happy with the way the design is turning out and everything seems to work, but now that my content is filling up the page I have realized that the page won't scroll, despite there being content below 'the fold'.

I'm guessing this is because I'm using CSS tables with fixed positions. I tried changing the position attribute to 'relative', and although this fixed the scrolling issue, it messed up the layout and I'm not sure how to make it work.

Here is the Fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/jbooth63/SKnsc/

And here is a link to a live preview of the code: http://www.financecapital.us/test/test.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 10px;
color: #333;}

body {
background-color: #fff;}

.socialcell {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 105px;
margin-left: 5px;
background-color: #ff9900;}


.headerimg {
position: fixed;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;}

.leftsidebar {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 155px;
margin-left: 5px;
background-color: #eee;
border-right: .1em dotted #369;
border-bottom: .1em dotted #369;}
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerimg"><img src="header2.jpg" title="Financing the world's equipment.">    
</div> 

<div class="socialcell">
<table width="300" height="50">
<tr>
<td><center>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/financecapitalut"><img src="facebook.png" title="Finance 
Capital on Facebook" height="40"></a>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/finance-capital-llc?trk=hb_tab_compy_id_477909#">  
<img src="linkedin.png" title="Finance Capital on LinkedIn" height="40"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/FinanceCap"><img src="twitter.png" title="@FinanceCap on 
Twitter" height="40">
</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy pal, I've done it by myself using chrome developer tools.

The problem is that you're using: "position: fixed;" on your divs.

Using "position: absolute;" on every div, should work.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is correct. Here is a fiddle showing what happens when you change all of your `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` http://jsfiddle.net/QEwRG/

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you - you are my hero!

Comment: @DrydenLong that link is now broken.